# Need to set a version or build number across a few files

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flashdevelop

I'm looking for a way to set a version or build number to match across a few files using Flashdevelop. I'd like it so that before I build my project I can set this version number quickly across all interested files simultaneously without having to open each file, select and paste the new value.

In my main AS file I have a variable set like so:

`private var version:String = "1.2.3.4";`

And in two other XML files I'd like to have the same version number appear, maybe like:

**File 1:**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data version="1.2.3.4">`

**File 2:**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data version="1.2.3.4">`

I'm doing it this way so as to quickly identify what version XMLs go with what version SWF.

Ideally I'd like a quick Flashdevelop way to perform this task but I'm open to suggestions to different applications and approaches.

Below is the brute force method I'm currently using as a macro in FlashDevelop which involves first highlighting the version number text and then executing the macro.

`ScintillaCommand|Copy
Edit|folder1\file1.xml
ScintillaCommand|DocumentStart
ScintillaCommand|LineDown
ScintillaCommand|WordRightEnd
ScintillaCommand|WordRightEnd
ScintillaCommand|WordRightEnd
ScintillaCommand|WordRightEnd
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|Paste
Edit|folder2\file2.xml
ScintillaCommand|DocumentStart
ScintillaCommand|LineDown
ScintillaCommand|WordRightEnd
ScintillaCommand|WordRightEnd
ScintillaCommand|WordRightEnd
ScintillaCommand|WordRightEnd
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|Paste
Edit|folder3\file3.xml
ScintillaCommand|DocumentStart
ScintillaCommand|LineDown
ScintillaCommand|WordRightEnd
ScintillaCommand|WordRightEnd
ScintillaCommand|WordRightEnd
ScintillaCommand|WordRightEnd
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|WordRightExtend
ScintillaCommand|Paste`

It's primative but it seems to work for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the list of 3rd party plugins: http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=3rd_Party_Plugins

Either AutoVersion or Version might be able to do the trick - I've used AutoVersion before, and aside from a few bugs (namely when creating interface files), it did the job. Not sure if it works on multiple files though

Comment: Thanks. I'll check those out. Right now I'm using a brute force macro method that seems to be working. I'm adding it to my post.